# Eclipse plugin development using SVN repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm developing an Eclipse pluging which is executed when I right clik on a project in Project Explorer view and choose my option in the menu. The thing is that I need to get location of the selected project in the svn repository. When you right click on any project and go to Properties there is always SVN Info listed, where I can also see the Resource URL. Do you know any way to get it programatically?

Thanks in advance for your help and commitment.

Comment: Both subclipse and subversive do this. Have You examined the sources?

Comment: I am new to this and I am not sure what do you mean by subeclipse and subversive. Can you please give me an example of this. Thanks for the reply

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/
http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

The Plug-In Selection Spy can be used to find out what code implements the currently active element within Eclipse.

For example open the Project Properties window and select the "Subversion" element (this is present for me as I have Subclipse installed). This displays a Properties page which includes the repository URL. Press Alt+Shift+F1 and you will get a popup listing the code which provided that page.

[image: spy screenshot]

If you open org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.properties.SVNPropertyPage (getting the source from the Subclipse site if you don't have it) you can start trying to work out where it gets the repository URL from.